# ReactJS : how can I pass a child component to its ancestor?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks, components, hierarchy

i'm working on a music app, but I'm quite new to ReactJS.

The structure of the components looks like this :

```
- Playlist
-- Player
-- Tracklist
--- Track
--- Track
--- Track
```

I would like to have a *currentTrack* state in my Playlist component, and the value of it would be a reference to the Track component that has been clicked (not just some data from that track).

Because I need to be able to access the Track's method from within the Playlist component : for instance, when a Track will be defined as the current one in the Playlist, there might be an old track that I need to unload.  I would thus need to update the state of that old track before setting the new one.

My components use React hooks, they are not classes.

How could I pass a reference of my Track component up to the Playlist component after it is clicked ?

Thanks !

Comment: if your components aren't classes what do you mean with `able to access the Track's method`? if possible provide some code to make your problem easier to understand

Comment: You are right. I would just need to update its state.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass events up using props (assuming that React redux is not an options for you).

Update based on comments:

```
// List of songs in playlist
const defaultSongs = [
    {'name': 'Cornerstone', 'artist': 'Arctic Monkeys'},
    {'name': 'Heart In a Cage', 'artist': 'The Strokes'},
    {'name': 'Backseat Freestyle', 'artist': 'Kendric Lamar'}
]

const PlayList = () => {
    const [songs, setSongs] = useState(defaultSongs);
    
    //Create active song state here.
    const [activeSong, setActiveSong] = useState(null);
    
    const updateActiveSong = (track) => {
     setActiveSong(track);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Player activeSong={activeSong}/>
            <TrackList activeSong = {activeSong} songs={songs} updateActiveSong={updateActiveSong}/>
        </>
    )
}

const TrackList = ({songs, updateActiveSong}) => {
    return (
        songs.map( song_information => 
            <Track 
                key={song_information.name}
                updateActiveSong={updateActiveSong}
                activeSong = {activeSong}
                {...song_information}
            />
        )
    )
}

const Track = (props) => {
    // NO STATE STORED HERE
    return (
        <>
            <div> {props.name} </div>
            <div> {props.artist} </div>
            <div> Is song active: {props.activeSong == props.name ? 'YES' : 'NO'} </div>
            // Onclick, update the song state in the parent component
            <button onClick = {() => props.updateActiveSong(props.name)}> 
                Play Me
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Well, you are only passing the song name; while I would need, I think, to pass the whole componenent (eg. so I can update its state).

Comment: Redux could be an option, but I have been told that you should avoid it when learning React, + that a lot of people were using it when not necessary.  But maybe I should ?

Comment: Hmmm... can you clarify this: `while I would need, I think, to pass the whole component`. Why would you need to pass the whole component? Basically, what information needs to be communicated from child to parent? If you are trying to setState of a child component from the parent (but the state is stored in child), then that breaks React's unidirectional data flow policy.

Comment: Yes, that was I would like to do :)  But i'm new to ReactJS and don't know the whole logic  yet, so what you said helps me.  But then should I handle this ?  Let's say that when a track is clicked/played, its 'active' state becomes True.  If a new track is played, the old one should have its 'active' state go False.  You see what I mean ? Or maybe I need a totally different logic but I don't see what.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'll update the code to reflect how to do that.

Comment: Hi Parmandeep and thanks a lot for your help.  I think I get the idea.  But is this a situation where I should consider using React ?

Comment: Yeah for sure. Even in most other languages, its a good idea to implement this data flow. (If you think about a python class- you store the attributes in the class itself, if they are used throughout your module, as opposed to a method in the class).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "consider using Redux" :) Thanks A LOT for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve what I wanted using the context API, after having read this article: [How to Replace Redux with React Hooks and the Context API](https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/).

I now have a "global state" for my playlist, that I can use in any sub component.
That's great !